# else if not working in Javascript with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I was executing code about window scrollTop where as you scroll up by 200 you have a div with one behaviour and if you cross 500px you would have div behave in another way. The later is not getting executed but just first one is executing. I am starting to learn javascript so please forgive me if this is a small fix :)  Here's the code:

```js
       window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
            document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "fixed";
            document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "green";
        } else if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {   
            document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "fixed";
            document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "pink";

         } else {
            document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "";
            document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "";
            }

     }//end function
```

```css
    *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

  body {height: 3000px;}

    .box {float: left; width: 100%; height: 70px; background: yellow; padding: 15px; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; position: relative;}
    .box h2 {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="meBox"><h2>I am Heading</h2></div>
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's because the first one get evaluated first and is always true, if it's bigger than 500 then it's bigger than 200 too. Put the if with 500 first.

Comment: Because 500 is greater than 200. If the first one is true, it will not keep checking the others.

Comment: put the > 500 in the if. then the > 200 in the else if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the first one get evaluated first and is always true, if it's bigger than 500 then it's bigger than 200 too. Put the if with 500 first.

Also no need to wrap the `myFunction` in another function to assign it to `onscroll`.

```
window.onscroll = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {   
        document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "pink";

     } else if(document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
        document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "green";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "";
        document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "";
    }

}//end function
```

Comment: Just wanted to answer the same :D

Answer (score 0):

Improve the conditions i.e. specify the upper-limit also

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
    var top = document.body.scrollTop;
    var elemTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (top > 200 && top <= 500 || elemTop > 200 && elemTop <= 500) {
      document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "fixed";
      document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "green";
    } else if (top > 500 || elemTop > 500) {
      document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "fixed";
      document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "pink";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("meBox").style.position = "";
      document.getElementById("meBox").style.background = "";
    }

  } //end function
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 3000px;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.box h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="meBox">
  <h2>I am Heading</h2>
</div>
```